# D3js and Variables Based on Percentages

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create a responsive scatterplot with D3js using percentages for the width and height of the chart.

So, I have these variables declared up top:

```
var w = '100%';
var h = '100%';
```

My `xScale` and `yScale` work properly, along with the placement of my output circles in the SVG:

```
    var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["ttc"]; })])
        .range([0, w]);

    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d["ctc"]; })])
        .range([0, h]);

    var svg = d3.select(el)
        .append('svg')
        .attr('height', h)
        .attr('width', w);


    svg.selectAll('circle')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx', function(d) { return xScale(d["ttc"]); })
        .attr('cy', function(d) { return yScale(d["ctc"]); })
        .attr('r', 10);
```

However, due to the nature of SVGs, the circles are displayed from the top left corner rather than the typical origin in the bottom left. In order to reverse this, usually I would switch the `yScale` `range` values, to be `[h, 0]` instead of `[0, h]`. When I do this, I get an error `Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cy="NaN"`. What can I do to fix this and have the plot work with percentages?

Comment: The scale can't interpolate the % value -- you can either use absolute values or use just the number 100 as maximum and add the % when evaluating the scale with a specific value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare width and height as numbers, like `var h = 100;` and then add percentages in the `attr` function:

```
.attr('cx', function (d) {
    return xScale(d["ttc"]) + '%';
})
```

Then your svg could be styled with:

```
.attr('height', h + '%')
.attr('width', w + '%')
```

Or just use CSS for that. Here's a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/819y0nbf/).

Comment: How could I create axes that adapt to `xScale` and `yScale`?

Comment: Personally, I would recommend to setup an event listener on window resize and re-render the graph with pixel values.

Comment: What size would you make your initial rendering, then, so that it is responsive to the size of the window it's opened in?

Comment: You look up the size of the container when you set `w` and `h` values, e.g. `var w = document.body.clientWidth;`